# Get active triggers in Zabbix API and take account of dependencies

Tags: zabbix

I have configured a trigger in Zabbix which gets active when there's no internet connectivity. All other triggers are depending on this trigger, so if there's no internet connection, only one trigger is getting active instead of all. This works as expected.

But when I get all active triggers via Zabbix API, it returns all triggers and does not take account of the configured dependencies.

This is how my API request looks like:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "trigger.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
                "selectTriggers": "extend",
                "selectGroups": "extend",
                "selectHosts": "extend",
                "withLastEventUnacknowledged": 1,
                "expandDescription": 1,
                "filter": {
                    "value": 1,
                    "status": 0
                },
                "sortfield": "priority",
                "sortorder": "DESC"
    },
    "id": 2,
    "auth": "XXX"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit later, but in Zabbix API v. 2.4-3.0 there is a flag "skipDependent".
So, the request will be

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "trigger.get",
"params": {
    "output": "extend",
    "skipDependent": "1",
    "selectTriggers": "extend",
    "selectGroups": "extend",
    "selectHosts": "extend",
    "withLastEventUnacknowledged": 1,
    "expandDescription": 1,
    "filter": {
        "value": 1,
        "status": 0
    },
    "sortfield": "priority",
    "sortorder": "DESC"
},
"id": 2,
"auth": "XXX"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to add: "selectDependencies": "true" to your request.
It's avaliable as a flag and as query.
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/trigger/get